# Random func playground swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I am in my playground. I was trying to use the `arc4random_uniform` func but I get this error: Use of unresolved identifier 'arc4random_uniform'

can I use another func instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one make random number between range for arc4random\_uniform()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132399/how-does-one-make-random-number-between-range-for-arc4random-uniform)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate, His question is specifically for playground.
I think that @Kirsteins answer is the good one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you at least have imported `import Foundation`. Or platform specific `import UIKit` for iOS or `import Cocoa` for OSX.

Comment: One of these three should always be in your playground.

Answer (score 1):

`arc4random_uniform` is apple platform only (from UIKit).
If your playground is hosted on linux, it should not work.

Use `rand()` or `Int/Double/Bool.Int.random()`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007169/5717295