# How do I make randomized floats?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I currently have a line of code which creates random numbers 1-5, but how do I include decimals, 1.00-5.00?

```
 stoptimer.text = String(arc4random_uniform(4)+1)
```

Comment: I think this link may help you: [double and float random numbers][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28075271/35499

Comment: You don't want a random float, you want a random int converted to float. That's not exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your Int to Double and use String(format:) method to format your string as desired:

```
stoptimer.text = String(format: "%.2f", Double(arc4random_uniform(5)+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the range of your generated numbers from 100 to 500 and devide the resulting one by 100.

```
stoptimer.text = String((arc4random_uniform(400)+100) / 100)
```

Comment: Note that arc4random_uniform won't include the upper bound value in the range of values returned ( it will be in the range [1.00-5.00[ ). Just making sure you know that.

Comment: I don't want 1.34 or 4.54. I only want 1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00