# Swift: spawn enemies at random times within a range?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Alright so I know this question has been answered for those asking in several other languages but it doesn't seem as though anyone has asked for Swift yet.

I'm creating a sprite kit game and I need to spawn my enemies at random times (within a 0-2 sec range). Right now I have them spawning every second using delays. Here is the enemy spawn func:

```
func spawnEnemy1() {
        var enemy1Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "enemy1")

        enemy1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: enemy1Texture)
        enemy1.setScale(0.3)
        enemy1.name = "enemy1"

        enemy1.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height * 1.2)
        enemy1.zPosition = 55

        var enemyPhysicsSize = CGSize(width: enemy1.size.width,height: 65)
        enemy1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: enemyPhysicsSize)
        enemy1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

        enemy1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy1.rawValue
        enemy1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Savior.rawValue
        enemy1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Savior.rawValue

        self.addChild(enemy1)

        let enemyMoveDown = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.5,-100), duration:5.6)

        let scaleEnemy = SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 5.6)

        let enemyScaleDown = SKAction.group([enemyMoveDown, scaleEnemy])

        enemy1.runAction(enemyScaleDown)
    }
```

Here is executing the spawn func:

```
let enemy1SpawnDelay = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)

        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
            SKAction.sequence([
                enemy1SpawnDelay,
                SKAction.runBlock({self.spawnEnemy1()}),
                SKAction.waitForDuration(5.6)])))
```

(I don't want multiple enemies on the screen at once and it takes 5.6 sec for the enemy to move down the screen, hence the last delay).

The `enemy1SpawnDelay` controls the amount of time that can pass between when the last enemy appeared and when the next will appear, so I need to know how I can make `enemy1SpawnDelay` be set equal to a new random number between 0-2 each time an enemy is spawned.

How can I do this? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of arc4random which returns a random value between 0 to your number

```
spawndelay = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yournumber))
```

For Double from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132399/how-does-one-make-random-number-between-range-for-arc4random-uniform)

```
func random(#lower: Double, upper: Double) -> Double {
    let r = Double(arc4random(UInt64)) / Double(UInt64.max)
    return (r * (upper - lower)) + lower
}
```

Comment: I need Doubles, not Ints. Could you look at my most recent question please?