# Getting a random CGFloat value from an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, random, cgfloat

I have an array that holds CGFloat values and I am trying to figure out how I would go about randomising through this array to get a random x co-ordinate:

```
let xAxisSpawnLocations: [CGFloat] = [screenWidth + 150, screenWidth + 100, screenWidth + 50 , screenWidth - 50, screenWidth - 100, screenWidth - 150]
```

because I have to put them into a line of code that will position an object on the map.

```
obstacle.position = CGPoint(x: ARRAY VALUE HERE, y: yAxisSpawnLocations[0])
```

I have tried looking up how to randomise through an array but it only has it for Int32 values.

Can some please provide and example on how to do this.

**Here is the full code for reference if you need to look at it:**

```
let xAxisSpawnLocations: [CGFloat] = [screenWidth + 150, screenWidth + 100, screenWidth + 50 , screenWidth - 50, screenWidth - 100, screenWidth - 150]
let yAxisSpawnLocations: [CGFloat] = [0]                          

        for xLocation in xAxisSpawnLocations {

            for (var i = 0; i < Int(numberOfObjectsInLevel); i++) {


            let obstacle:Object = Object()

            obstacle.theType = LevelType.road


            obstacle.createObject()
            addChild(obstacle)



            obstacle.position = CGPoint(x: xLocation, y: yAxisSpawnLocations[0])
            obstacle.zPosition = 9000
           // addChild(greenFrog)
        }
      }
    }
```

The xLocation needs to be replaced by the randomiser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one make random number between range for arc4random\_uniform()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132399/how-does-one-make-random-number-between-range-for-arc4random-uniform)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Pick a random element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're array may be storing `CGFloat` values, the array indexes will still be integers. Arrays always have integer based indexes regardless of what they are storing.

You simply want to generate a random integer between 0 and the length of the array and access the element at that index:

```
let randx = xAxisSpawnLocations[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xAxisSpawnLocations.count)))]
obstacle.position = CGPoint(x: randx, y: yAxisSpawnLocations[0])
```

Comment: biggest rookie mistake by me I forgot all about indexes. xD But yes that did solve my problem thank you.