# How to interpolate from number in one range to a corresponding value in another range?

Tags: swift, integer, range

I currently receive a Int that could be anywhere between 0 and 180,000. I need to change it to fit between 0 and 3000. I know in other languages you can use something like

```
Map(min1,max1,min2,max2,input)
```

I can't seem to find something like that inside of swift.
This is what I currently have, but it always returns 0.

```
var newY = [(Int)(input)]
newY = newY.map {_ in 0 * 3000}
print(newY[0])
```

I think I am using the wrong function. I have never done any mapping in Swift before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132399/how-does-one-make-random-number-between-range-for-arc4random-uniform

Comment: What does "keep a number between two numbers" mean? Do you want to generate a random number?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but documentation on `map` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Comment: Lets say you get a value `3003`: should this be mapped to `3`, or to an integer of the size `~3000*3003/180000` (`~50`)?

Comment: Which other language does your example come from?  It might be easier to answer your question if I could see the definition of how that one behaves.

Comment: @sahil not a duplicate, that question deals with random numbers.  This question has to do with bounding a number.

Comment: @PhillipMills Here is where I am getting my example from https://processing.org/reference/map_.html

Comment: @dfri It should be mapped like `~3000*3003/180000 (~50`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `map` function on collections is going to do something very different.  It applies a mapping function to each element of a collection and returns a new collection based on the results.

What you're looking for would be:

```
func map(minRange:Int, maxRange:Int, minDomain:Int, maxDomain:Int, value:Int) -> Int {
    return minDomain + (maxDomain - minDomain) * (value - minRange) / (maxRange - minRange)
}

print(map(minRange: 0, maxRange: 1800000, minDomain: 0, maxDomain: 3000, value: 200000))
```

With only a little more work you can make it generic over all integer types:

```
func map<T:IntegerArithmetic>(minRange:T, maxRange:T, minDomain:T, maxDomain:T, value:T) -> T {
    return minDomain + (maxDomain - minDomain) * (value - minRange) / (maxRange - minRange)
}
```

Another option would be to take advantage of the Swift `Range` type to make calling more succinct:

```
func map<T:IntegerArithmetic>(range:Range<T>, domain:Range<T>, value:T) -> T {
    return domain.lowerBound + (domain.upperBound - domain.lowerBound) * (value - range.lowerBound) / (range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
}

map(range:0..<3000, domain:0..<180000, value: 1500)
```

Comment: There's a substantial difference between dfri's answer and mine in that due to the order of operations mine will have more even distribution while his is less likely to result in overflows.  All depends on what you're looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to suggest a different name of the new function, to avoid confusion with the existing `map`?

Comment: Probably, I was just keeping his name intact.

Comment: Combined with explicit parameter naming, it seems clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that works for both `Double` and `Float`:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
  /// Allows mapping between reverse ranges, which are illegal to construct (e.g. `10..<0`).
  func interpolated(
    fromLowerBound: Self,
    fromUpperBound: Self,
    toLowerBound: Self,
    toUpperBound: Self) -> Self
  {
    let positionInRange = (self - fromLowerBound) / (fromUpperBound - fromLowerBound)
    return (positionInRange * (toUpperBound - toLowerBound)) + toLowerBound
  }

  func interpolated(from: ClosedRange<Self>, to: ClosedRange<Self>) -> Self {
    interpolated(
      fromLowerBound: from.lowerBound,
      fromUpperBound: from.upperBound,
      toLowerBound: to.lowerBound,
      toUpperBound: to.upperBound)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
50.interpolated(from: 0...100, to: 0...10) == 5
3.interpolated(from: 1...5, to: 0...10) == 5
4.interpolated(from: 1...5, to: 1...10) == 7.75
11.interpolated(
  fromLowerBound: 10,
  fromUpperBound: 20,
  toLowerBound: 100,
  toUpperBound: 120) == 102
11.interpolated(
  fromLowerBound: 10,
  fromUpperBound: 20,
  toLowerBound: 120,
  toUpperBound: 100) == 118
11.interpolated(
  fromLowerBound: 20,
  fromUpperBound: 10,
  toLowerBound: 100,
  toUpperBound: 120) == 118
11.interpolated(
  fromLowerBound: 20,
  fromUpperBound: 10,
  toLowerBound: 120,
  toUpperBound: 100) == 102
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Map function
func mapy(n:Double, start1:Double, stop1:Double, start2:Double, stop2:Double) -> Double {
    return ((n-start1)/(stop1-start1))*(stop2-start2)+start2;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are looking for mapping the relative position of a value in a given range to another range, you could do something along the lines:

```
// dummy function name
func transform(_ number: Int, fromRange: (Int, Int), toRange: (Int, Int)) -> Int? {
    guard number >= fromRange.0 && number <= fromRange.1,
        toRange.0 <= toRange.1 else { return nil }
    return toRange.0 + (number-fromRange.0)*(toRange.1-toRange.0)/(fromRange.1-fromRange.0)
}

// ex1
let numberA = 3001
let transformedNumberA = transform(numberA, fromRange: (0, 180_000), toRange: (0,3000))
print(transformedNumberA ?? -1) // 50

// ex2
let numberB = 134_000
let transformedNumberB = transform(numberB, fromRange: (0, 180_000), toRange: (0,3000))
print(transformedNumberB ?? -1) // 2233

// ex3
let numberC = 200_000
let transformedNumberC = transform(numberC, fromRange: (0, 180_000), toRange: (0,3000))
print(transformedNumberC ?? -1) // -1 (nil return)
```

Just take care to notice that `(number-fromRange.0)*(toRange.1-toRange.0)` (left associativity of `/` and `*` operators) may overflow.

Comment: You need to subtract the minimum input range value before math, otherwise it only works if the input range starts at zero.

Answer (score 0):

*It's not clear whether the OP simply wants to clamp (title seems to say that) or wants to interpolate from one bounding range to another. The title makes me think one, but the dual max/min values make me think they're after an interpolation. I answered the former. David Berry has a good answer for the latter.*

What you *may* want is min/max functions. Swift has these. To "clamp" a value between a low and high value, you usually combine the two:

```
var bottom = 13
var top = 42
var tooLow = 7
var clamped = min(top, max(bottom, tooLow)) -> 13
var justRight = 23
clamped = min(top, max(bottom, justRight)) --> 23
var tooHigh = 99
clamped = min(top, max(bottom, tooHigh))  --> 42
```

This is usually the route most people go, and is probably good enough for most. I personally hate writing that again and again, and I get tired of having to think about which side to feed into the max and the min. And I don't like that it uses what looks like a free function, I'm an object oriented message sending sort of guy, so I do the following:

```
precedencegroup MinMaxPrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: NilCoalescingPrecedence, AdditionPrecedence, MultiplicationPrecedence
}

infix operator <> : MinMaxPrecedence

func <><T:Comparable>(a:T, b:T) -> T {
    return a < b ? a : b
}

infix operator >< : MinMaxPrecedence

func ><<T:Comparable>(a:T, b:T) -> T {
    return a < b ? b : a
}
```

Basically, this defines two new operators (`<>` and `><`) that can be used between any type that adopts `Comparable`. They're easy for me to remember, the one that tucks in smaller wants the smaller value, and the one that opens up bigger returns the bigger value. What's nice is that you can then put them in simpler expressions:

```
var bottom = 13
var top = 42
var tooLow = 7
var justRight = 23
var tooHigh = 99
bottom >< tooLow <> top --> 13
bottom >< justRight <> top --> 23
bottom >< tooHigh <> top --> 42
```

Comment: Although I agree it's not absolutely clear, his `map` function takes two ranges which implies he's actually wanting to interpolate.  Combine that with having seen a `map` function somewhere somewhen that does exactly that, it seems likely that's what they're actually wanting.

Comment: Yup, realized that was likely after writing all of the above out. :(

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the simd_mix function...

```
import simd

func remap(sourceMin: Float, sourceMax: Float, destMin: Float, destMax: Float, t: Float) -> Float {
    let f = (t - sourceMin) / (sourceMax - sourceMin)
    return simd_mix(destMin, destMax, f)
}
```