# Convert Java Math.random to Swift 4

Tags: java, swift

I was wondering how I can convert the below java code to Swift 4.

```
int randomNoteIndex = myArray[0] + (int) (Math.random() * (myArray[1] - myArray[0] + 1));
```

Here is what i tried but I always get the same number myArray[0] everytime

```
 let randomNoteIndex = myArray[0] +  Int(arc4random_uniform(1) * (UInt32(myArray[1]) - UInt32(myArray[0]) + UInt32(1)))
```

Comment: You should investigate what API actually does before blindly converting code. See [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132399/how-does-one-make-random-number-between-range-for-arc4random-uniform), that should help.

Comment: Thanks for the link @M.Prokhorov it helped clear things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lowerBound + (int) (Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound + 1))` returns a uniformly distributed random number in range `[lowerBound, upperBound]`.

`arc4random_uniform(upperBound)` returns a uniformly distributed random number less than `upperBound`. Thus what you're asking should be:

```
lowerBound + arc4random_uniform(upperBound - lowerBound + 1)
```

As Jacob stated, `arc4random_uniform(myArray.count)` returns a random "index", not number in range. Probably he deduced this from the naming of your variable.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it was more in line with what I needed. However Jacob's answer helped me understand the issue. I was able to use your answer and get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`arc4random_uniform` returns a random value between 0 and the argument passed in -1. Therefore if you pass in 1, you'll only ever get 0 out.

The behaviour you want can be achieved by passing in the array count. For example:

`let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(Int32(myArray.count)))`

Note the casts, this is because `arc4random_uniform` is C derived so requires explicit typing.